# Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra: Chapter 12.1 Lemma 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm having trouble understanding part 2 of the lemma 8 as seen below.

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding what $p(R/(a))$ would be. It seems like $p(R/(a)) = \{pr+(a)\colon r \in R \}$, but I am having trouble seeing how this is $(p)+(a)/(a)$. Also, I am having trouble understanding what $(a)/(a)$ is as it seems like $(a)/(a) = \{ra +(a) \colon ra \in (a) \} = \{0 \colon ra \in (a) \}$.

I'm also having trouble understanding how to derive the conclusion from $p(R/(a)) = (p)+(a)/(a)$.

Thanks for your help!